# Angular bar chart tool tip series not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

hi i am using angular bar chart it's working fine but i am not able to show tool tip the series is not working fine here i attached my code my expectation is i need to show tool tip when cursor move to bar in each have year and data i need to show in tool tip

## html

```
  <html ng-app="app">

    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>  


    </head>

    <body ng-controller="ChartController">

        <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
        </canvas>
    </body>

    </html>
```

## Controller

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("ChartController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Year', 'Data'];

  $scope.data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not have any issues, but make sure you have refered the correct versions, i see you are missing reference for angular-chart.js

**EDIT:**

You need to do a simple hack inorder to modify the tool tip by modifying the **`chartOptions`**

```
  vm.chartOptions = {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              var legend = new Array();
              var item =  "Year:"+ tooltipItem.xLabel + "Data:"+tooltipItem.yLabel ;
              legend.push(item);
              return legend;
            }
          }
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fnQUSElQhMpsit0yzs8s?p=preview)**

Comment: chart wokring fine but series not shown?i need to show like Year:2007 Data:80 like that @sajeetharan

Comment: u  get my expectation output?

Comment: @jose did it help ?

Comment: yah thanks if i have any more doubts in angular chart i will ping.

Comment: i have doubt  how to show tooltip always inside the chart help!